# save string to a date field in sql server

Tags: sql-server, case

I have the following string that I need to save to a sql server database column that has a date datatype.

'2017-05-25T00:00:00'

Can I use cast within a insert script to save this value and is this the best way?

Comment: yes u can .. `select cast('2017-05-25T00:00:00' as date)`

Answer (score 0):

yes You can insert the value like this

```
INSERT INTO YourTable(ColumnName)
SELECT CAST(StringFiled AS DATETIME)
```

You Can cast it as Date,DateTime or any other Date type you need

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the following options.

```
insert into myTable
values (CAST('2017-05-25T00:00:00' as datetime))

insert into myTable
values (Convert(varchar(30),'2017-05-25T00:00:00',102))
```